# Create a code with randomly skipped/duplicated bit?

Tags: coding-theory

Is it possible to create an error correcting code (linear or non linear) that is capable of handling a single skipped or duplicated bit?

So lets assume that I transmit the code 1101
then the possible codes which could be received are:

```
1101, //No error 
101, 101, 111, 111, //Skipped bit 
11101, 11101, 11001, 11011 // Duplicated bit
```

**EDIT - clarifications:**

1) The code also needs to handle at least 1 randomly flipped bit.
The flipping is guaranteed to happen before the skip/duplicate.

2) The bits come in as a stream and there is no synchronization signalling the start or end of a codeword.
However there is one significant advantage: the codeword being sent is repeated infinitely. eg. 1110111101111011011101 ... (3x duplicated, 1x skipped, 1x no error)

3) So another way to ask the question is:
given the kind of noise attacks referred to above what is the minimal number of bits I would need to receive for a code of rank k before I can gaurantee detection of the code and how would it be encoded?

Comment: Usually, one assumes that the number of bits sent will equal the number of bits received.

Comment: I updated with clarification

Comment: A relevant survey: "Reliable Communication over Channels with Insertions, Deletions and Substitutions" Matthew C. Davey and David J.C. MacKay  (2000) http://www.inference.eng.cam.ac.uk/mcdavey/papers/watermark.html

Answer (score 0):

After considerable research on the topic it seems that the best reference
for answering the posted question is ["Codes for Correcting Insertion and Deletion Errors" by Patrick A. H. Bours.](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/2495185/418412.pdf)

The basic idea is to create a Comma Free Code with some minimal Levenshtein distance.